# Cognos on startup sends a test email to the notification default sender. How can this email be stopped or changed?

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

We have a cron job that automates the stop and start of cognos.
When Cognos Starts an email is automatically sent with the following subject "Test message from IBM Cognos Configuration" 
This email is sent every day to the address in the config (notification) based on the property for the default sender

Is there a way to stop this test email (which is part of the test when Cognos starts)? or change the recipient or process?

Note: We want to keep default sender field. ie when a user sends a report via email does not have an email address associated with their profile, the default sender from IBM Cognos Configuration will be used.

In an effort to find the source of this test email I tried
grep -Ril "Test message from IBM Cognos Configuration" /

Which shows

/opt/ibm/cognos/analytics/bin/cnfgtest_en.properties

/opt/ibm/cognos/analytics/bin/cnfgtest_ca.properties

/opt/ibm/cognos/analytics/bin/cnfgtest_el.properties

/opt/ibm/cognos/analytics/bin/cnfgtest_id.properties

/opt/ibm/cognos/analytics/bin/cnfgtest_in.properties

/opt/ibm/cognos/analytics/bin/cnfgtest_ms.properties

/opt/ibm/cognos/analytics/bin/cnfgtest_sk.properties

/opt/ibm/cognos/analytics/msgsdk/cnfgtest_en.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe able to use the the -notest 
Starts IBM Cognos Configuration with the automatic testing tasks disabled.
./cogconfig.sh -notest

For reference the following cogconfig command line options URL contains all the command line options available.  https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEP7J_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.inst_cr_winux.doc/c_zig_commandlineoptions.html